# Cannot prove limit of a fraction as $x$ goes to $-2$ from the left

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -2^-} \frac{1}{x+2}=-\infty$$

Here's what I have so far:

For all $M>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $-2-\delta<x<-2$ than $\frac{1}{x+2} < -M$

$$\frac{1}{x+2} < -M$$
$$\iff x+2 > \frac{1}{-M}$$

We pick $M = \frac{1}{\delta}$ and get the following:

$$x+2 > \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{\delta}}$$
$$x+2 > -\delta$$

But I can't get from $x+2 > -\delta$ to $-2-\delta<x<-2$ in order to prove the limit. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x < -2 $ because it's a limit from the left, so you don't have to worry about that part at this point. See if you can manipulate that last inequality of yours to $-2-\delta < x $.

Comment: Oh, so I can just do $x+2>-\delta \iff x>-2-\delta \iff -2-\delta<x<-2$ QED

Comment: That's right! Except use '\blacksquare' instead of QED; They mean the same but the black box is more in style.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M>0$. Then, taking $\delta:=\frac{1}{M}$, we have
\begin{align}
0<-2-x<\delta&\implies-\delta<x+2<0\\
&\implies-\frac{1}{\delta}>\frac{1}{x+2}\\
&\implies\frac{1}{x+2}<-M
\end{align}